# SQL Database Mail - HTML Body format

Tags: html, sql, database, email

Is there a limit on characters at @body_message when using HTML format? Whenever im sending email thru sql mail, it's not complete and also send some html tags at the end of the message. please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the @body parameter is set to nvarchar(max) so no, there is no limit to the body.  Can you post what you are trying to send?

Answer (score 0):

`VARCHAR MAX` is able to hold 8000 characters.

`NVARCHAR MAX` is able to hold 4000 characters.

Unfortunately in the system stored proc `sp_send_dbmail` MS set the body to `NVARCHAR` so it would limit to 4000 characters.

BUT you can build a proc or a query and stick that into the `@Query` and the the results of that query will go into the email.